# How to manage Python crawlers?

Tags: python, memory-management, web-crawler

I have many python's scripts for crawling web contents. They have different start, stop time and wait time until the next crawl. Right now I have about 50 crawlers and will be more in the future. So how can I manage them so they does not take much of computer resoures.
At the moment for 1 crawler I make 1 window service for it so it can run independently and I also use time.sleep to wait to the next crawl.
I end up with about 30MB of RAM for each crawler. It's okay with small amount of crawler but I think it's not scalable.
And not just crawler but also schedule scripts as well.
Please share your thought on this.

Comment: You haven't provided much detail about your scripts, so it's difficult to provide much guidance.  Which python modules are you using?

Comment: Sometime I use requests.get to get html and then use BeautifulSoup to parse the content. sometime i use selenium for website using ajax